# Error while trying to debug demandware pipeline code using eclipse

Tags: salesforce, pipeline, demandware

After setting up the configuration for pipeline and clicking on debug in eclipse, I get this error.

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Digital Server Upload' on project 'DigitalServer'.
Tree element '/' not found.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue @pawan?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, I was able to solve the issue. Using new workspace and removing cartridges from business manager which was not in my local pc fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t need to edit Pipelines, I recommend VS Code with the Prophet plugin. Check it out on the VS Code plugin marketplace.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqrTT.prophet

Answer (score 1):

Check the project references (right click > Properties > Project References) of your connection to the instance. You likely have a closed or missing cartridge project referenced there. Once you remove this reference, the error will be gone.

Comment: Downgrading to eclipse photon resolved the issue. Now pipeline debugger works but script debugger gives "Could not connect to server: null" error.